# TTL and transaction rollback in YugabyteDB YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

When TTL is defined at table level, say, 5 seconds. If a transaction is taking more than 5 seconds after inserting a record, then the transaction will be rolled back (at time of commit), correct?. Also, can I change the TTL at a session level when starting a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Note that YCQL doesn't have client-controlled transactions that’s available only in YSQL, so you can't change the table TTL like that.

The transaction won't be rolled back though. TTL is enforced when you try to read the row (the insert time of the row will be checked against it’s TTL).